# I am getting assertion errors when using PYPJLINK , how could I fix them?

Tags: python, python-2.7, assertion, projector

Pypjlink is a universal projector control API to be able to control projectors over a network. Here is a link that will contain all of the information about it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypjlink. There is also a link to the repository that contains all of the files. I have been trying to get past all of the assertion errors, but I have not been having too much success. As soon as I fix one, another one is still in my way. I am simply querying the projector for the power status. Here is the code in my file:

```
from pypjlink import Projector
projector = Projector.from_address('10.21.24.7')

power =  projector.get('POWR')


print power
```

This is all of my outputs from testing over the last hour or two:

```
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get_errors()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 172, in get_errors
    param = self.get('ERST')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 71, in send_command
    resp_body, resp_param = parse_response(f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 30, in parse_response
    assert header == '%'
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('Power?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 67, in send_command
    data = to_binary(req_body, req_param)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 18, in to_binary
    assert body.isupper()
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('Power')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 67, in send_command
    data = to_binary(req_body, req_param)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 18, in to_binary
    assert body.isupper()
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('POWER')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 67, in send_command
    data = to_binary(req_body, req_param)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 20, in to_binary
    assert len(body) == 4
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('POW')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 67, in send_command
    data = to_binary(req_body, req_param)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 20, in to_binary
    assert len(body) == 4
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('POWE')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 71, in send_command
    resp_body, resp_param = parse_response(f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 30, in parse_response
    assert header == '%'
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('%POW')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 71, in send_command
    resp_body, resp_param = parse_response(f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 30, in parse_response
    assert header == '%'
AssertionError
>>> -m unittest discover pypjlink.tests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> unittest discover pypjlink.tests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> discover pypjlink.tests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('%POW')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 71, in send_command
    resp_body, resp_param = parse_response(f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 30, in parse_response
    assert header == '%'
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('POW')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 67, in send_command
    data = to_binary(req_body, req_param)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 20, in to_binary
    assert len(body) == 4
AssertionError
>>> 
=== RESTART: /Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py ===

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/OneDrive/School Work/Work Study/pjlink_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    power =  projector.get('POWR')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/projector.py", line 119, in get
    success, response = protocol.send_command(self.f, body, '?')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 71, in send_command
    resp_body, resp_param = parse_response(f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pypjlink/protocol.py", line 30, in parse_response
    assert header == '%'
AssertionError
>>>
```

Some extra information: I am connecting the projector over a network with a static IP. It is a BenQ projector, and I do have a pjlink command list. If I try to send a command, it will work, but I still get that error. The program just has a hard time receiving responses.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `projector.authenticate('some_auth')` after creating the projector object (just use a dummy name if you do not have auth.)
I would also use `get_power()` rather `get('POWR')` but you might have reasons.

Answer (score 0):

With our new asyncio pjlink library (https://github.com/HEInventions/aiopjlink) you can do this within a context manager:

```py
async with PJLink(address="10.21.24.7", password="secretpassword") as link:
    print("power =", await link.power.get())
```